# Tag manager error upon sending items array in PURCHASE event in Analytics

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-tag-manager

I am coding an app for Android in Kotlin and I Tried to log a `PURCHASE` even as shown here in the docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/measure-ecommerce?hl=en&authuser=0#make_purchase_refund but got the following errors:

```
E/GoogleTagManager: Internal error - Function call: __md_main
    Type not supported: class [Landroid.os.Parcelable;
E/GoogleTagManager: Internal error - Function call: __md_main
    Type not supported: class [Landroid.os.Parcelable;
E/GoogleTagManager: Internal error - Function call: __fm_sendFirebaseEvent
    Type not supported: class [Landroid.os.Parcelable;
```

This only happens when the parameter `FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEMS` is present and has an array in it, which is exactly one of the things I require.

This is the code:

```
        val firebaseAnalytics = Firebase.analytics

        val itemJeggings = Bundle().apply {
            putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "SKU_123")
            putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "jeggings")
            putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_CATEGORY, "pants")
            putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_VARIANT, "black")
            putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_BRAND, "Google")
            putDouble(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.PRICE, 9.99)
        }

        val itemJeggingsCart = Bundle(itemJeggings).apply {
            putLong(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.QUANTITY, 2)
        }

        firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.PURCHASE) {
            param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.TRANSACTION_ID, "T12345")
            param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.AFFILIATION, "Google Store")
            param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CURRENCY, "USD")
            param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.VALUE, 14.98)
            param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.TAX, 2.58)
            param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SHIPPING, 5.34)
            param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.COUPON, "SUMMER_FUN")
            param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEMS, arrayOf(itemJeggingsCart))
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should post the ITEMS array example, something like this should work:

```
val firebaseAnalytics = Firebase.analytics

val itemJeggings = Bundle().apply {
    putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "SKU_123")
    putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "jeggings")
    putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_CATEGORY, "pants")
    putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_VARIANT, "black")
    putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_BRAND, "Google")
    putDouble(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.PRICE, 9.99)
}

val itemJeggingsCart = Bundle(itemJeggings).apply {
    putLong(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.QUANTITY, 2)
}

val itemShirts = Bundle().apply {
    putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "SKU_123")
    putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "jeggings")
    putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_CATEGORY, "pants")
    putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_VARIANT, "black")
    putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_BRAND, "Google")
    putDouble(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.PRICE, 9.99)
}

val itemShirtsCart = Bundle(itemShirts).apply {
    putLong(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.QUANTITY, 3)
}

firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.PURCHASE) {
    param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.TRANSACTION_ID, "T12345")
    param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.AFFILIATION, "Google Store")
    param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CURRENCY, "USD")
    param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.VALUE, 14.98)
    param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.TAX, 2.58)
    param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SHIPPING, 5.34)
    param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.COUPON, "SUMMER_FUN")
    param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEMS, arrayOf(itemJeggingsCart, itemShirtsCart))
}
```